# Comparing dates with PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to compare today and a given date in PHP, and I am getting some unexpected results.

Here is some output I have:

```
echo time(); // 1315940430 
echo strtotime("+20 days", $date_string); // 1730010
echo $date_string; // 2010-9-30
```

and when I try something like this:

```
if (date() > date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+20 days", $date_string))) 
{

}
```

And the check always returns true no matter what the $date_string is.  Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: date() takes at least one parameter

Comment: Just curious: What you tried for `$date_string`? `1730010` seems way to low for ... lets say: some serious date.

Comment: I am using these two dates 2010-9-30 and 2011-9-11, but these comparisons are always true.  Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (date('Y-m-d') > date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+20 days", $date_string))) 
{

}
```

---

#### Update:

The reason is because the 2nd part of your if statement is in `1970`!

That's why it always returns true.

See demo: http://codepad.org/tmmuoSXv

Code:

```
<?php
$date_string = '2010-05-02';
$date_now = date('Y-m-d');
$converted = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+20 days", $date_string));

echo $date_now.PHP_EOL.$converted.PHP_EOL;

if ($date_now > $converted) 
{
   echo 'hello'.PHP_EOL;
}

echo 'there'.PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Output:

> 2011-09-13
> 1970-01-21
> hello
> there

---

### SOLVED:

What you to do is this:

```
$converted = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+20 days", strtotime($date_string)));
```

The extra `strtotime` fixes it all up for you and you get the correct date :-)

Demo: http://codepad.org/Fhnx5er0
Demo(if is false): http://codepad.org/jsnEMUGI

Comment: did you check what both of them return?

Comment: You would compare '2011-09-13' with '2011-10-03' (for example). How should that work? I'll guess PHP would cast it to int (which results in comparsion of 2011 vs. 2011) which would result in TRUE.

Comment: @breiti -- no, php does string comparison pretty well, it **does not** convert to an int.

Answer (score 1):

Convert both dates to timestamps (`date('U')`) and do `if ($date1 > $date2)`.

Answer (score 1):

`date()` takes at least one argument (the format).

Try this:

```
if (date('U') > strtotime("+20 days", $date_string)) {
```

The `U` format specifier returns the timestamp; just like strtotime(); so you can compare its output directly to the output of strtotime.

This is also a good solution:

```
if (date_create() > date_create($date_string)->modify('+20 days')) {
```

Comment: Hmmm, seems to be still always returning true.

Answer (score 0):

You want to compare the timestamps:

```
if (time() > strtotime("+20 days", $date_string))
{

}
```

Comment: For some reason that always returns true also. :(

Comment: This will also compare hours minutes and seconds.  It looks like the OP just wants to compare dates

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to play around with the new date functionality, you could also try something like this:

```
// If $otherday is in the future
if ( (int)date_diff(new DateTime(), new DateTime($otherday))->format("%r%a") > 0 ) {
   // ... blah
}
```

For example:

```
foreach ( array("1 year", "1 month", "1 week", "1 day", "1 hour") as $adjustment ) {
  printf("-/+ $adjustment %d/%d\n",
    date_diff(new DateTime(), new DateTime("-$adjustment"))->format("%r%a"),
    date_diff(new DateTime(), new DateTime("+$adjustment"))->format("%r%a")
  );
}
```

Output:

```
-/+ 1 year -365/366
-/+ 1 month -31/30
-/+ 1 week -7/7
-/+ 1 day -1/1
-/+ 1 hour 0/0
```

See [date_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) and [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) and [DateInterval::format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)